# mapping semaphore memory values about the sensors in the Android NDK - C/embed

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, embedded

Does the Android NDK expose the values generated by the sensors in pre-defined portions of memory so i can do something like this

```
T* ptr = 0x124
```

?

It's this possible and it's this being standardized by the Android team ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  And it's pretty inconceivable that they would do this.

The NDK keeps you much more isolated from the hardware than even a typical C-on-unix environment would, both mandatorily due to the security model, and also advisably due to the major variability of these details between the numerous Android versions and vendors.

Comment: so how to access the data from sensors ?

Comment: can you offer a specific example using C/C++ for the NDK ? Even a really basic one but I would like to have an idea about how this works for the NDK.

Comment: That's the purpose of the Android developer documentation, not of stack overflow.  Incidentally, the sensors were originally only accessible to applications from Java, though gradually some have been made available in native APIs.